# The space $c_{00}$ is direct sum of $M$ and $N$ but projections are not continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I don't know how to finish this problem because I don't know how to write the projections. If there is an alternative approach I would like to know it too (I suspect there may be one because $||\cdot||_1$ is not the usual norm on $c_{00}$). The problem is:

In $(c_{00},||\cdot||_1)$ consider
$$
M=\{x\in c_{00}: x(2n)=nx(2n-1) \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\} \\
N=\{x\in c_{00}: x(2n-1)=0 \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
I have to prove that $M$ and $N$ are closed, $M+N=c_{00}$ is direct but projections are not continuous. I proceed as follows:

Consider $f_n:c_{00}\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ given by $f_n(x)=x(n) \ \forall x\in c_{00}$ (here $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). Clearly $f_n$ is linear and $|f_n(x)|=|x(n)|\leq ||x||_1 \ \forall x\in c_{00}$, so it is continuous. Moreover, $g_n=f_{2n}-nf_{2n-1}$ is also a continuous linear functional. We can see $$N=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\ker f_{2n-1} \\
M=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\ker g_{n}
$$
As $f_n, g_n$ are continuous their kernels are closed and therefore $M$ and $N$ are closed. To see that $M+N=c_{00}$, note that $e_{2n} \in N \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ (here $e_n$ is the sequence whose terms are zero except for the n-th term, which is one) and $ne_{2n}+e_{2n-1} \in M \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, so we have that $e_n \in M+N \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and as $c_{00}$ is the linear expansion of the $e_n$'s, $M+N=c_{00}$. If $x\in M\cap N$ then $x=0$ and the sum is direct.

How can I prove that projections are not continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $M\cap N=\{0\}.$ The element $e_{2n-1}$ has the unique representation $$e_{2n-1}=(ne_{2n}+e_{2n-1})-ne_{2n}$$ in $M+N.$ The projection $P_N$ of $e_{2n-1}$ onto $N$ gives $P_Ne_{2n-1}=-ne_{2n}.$ Therefore it is unbounded.

**Remark** Every element $x$ of $c_{00}$ has the unique representation of the form $x=x_M+x_N,$ where $x_M\in M$ and $x_N\in N.$ Then the projections $P_M$ and $P_N$ are defined by $P_Mx=x_M$ and $P_Nx=x_N.$

Comment: +1. This clarifies also my question about which projections were being considered.